# Exception is rethrown multiple times not being caught by ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

My app is a Spring Boot web application.  I'm having a unique problem catching my exception with my ExceptionHandler - I think it is because the exception is being thrown and rethrown multiple times in my app flow.

Here is a high level description of the problem:

1. I throw ExceptionType1 in my service.
2. My ExceptionType1 exception is caught by my ErrorController class's error() method

```
@Override
@RequestMapping
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> error(HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean isErr = (boolean) request.getAttribute("filter.error");
    if (isErr) {
        //the error was thrown by cta filter, throw ExceptionType2
        throw new ExceptionType2(errorMsg, errorCode);
    } else {
        //handle other errors
```

I catch the error, convert the  ExceptionType1 exception to ExceptionType2 exception and rethrow it as ExceptionType2

3. The ExceptionType2 exception thrown above is caught by my ExceptionHandler class

```
@Component  
@ControllerAdvice  
public class MyExceptionHandler {    
@ExceptionHandler({ExceptionType2.class})    
public final String handleExceptionType2(ExceptionType2 e) throws ExceptionType3 {      
throw new ExceptionType3(errorMsg, errorCode);   
}
```

The ExceptionHandler above has an @ExceptionHandler method that catches the ExceptionType2 error thrown in the previous step, converts this exception to ExceptionType3 and rethrows it.
5. Here's my problem.  There is yet another ExceptionHandler class that is supposed to catch ExceptionType3 errors - but it is not working.  I put a breakpoint in my @ExceptionHandler method for ExceptionType3 and it is never hit

TLDR -- I basically catch an exception in my code - then it is

1. converted to another exception type and
2. rethrown as the new exception type 3 times in my code.

It works the first 2 times but the last time I try to convert the exception and rethrow it as ExceptionType3 - it is not caught by my ExceptionHandler class for ExceptionType3.

My theory right now is - I have converted exception type and rethrown the exception too many times.  Is there some limitation on this in Spring?  The reason I think this is - if I create and throw ExceptionType3 at any point in the above steps before step 5 - it is able to be caught by the appropriate ExceptionHandler class.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Spring does not allow handling of exceptions re-thrown from other exception handlers. Exception handler is supposed to be a final point where exception should be converted to HTTP response or just logged.

One of the way (maybe a little dirty) to solve your issue is to call handler for `ExceptionType3` manually.